# Class variables getting changed somehow

Tags: c++, class, variables

i am writing some classes for class and for some reason my private variables are getting changed somehow after the constructor sets them. In my code the x,y values for each instance of point are getting saved as very small numbers that aren't close to what they really are at all. When i cout some of the stored values after the constructor is run the values are correct but when calling my slope or length function they are passed the completely wrong values resulting in 0 for the length and "nan" for the slope. Any idea why this is happening?

LineSegment.hpp

```
#include "Point.hpp"

#ifndef LineSegment_hpp
#define LineSegment_hpp

class LineSegment
{
private:
    Point endp1;
    Point endp2;

    double x_1;
    double x_2;
    double y_1;
    double y_2;

public:
    LineSegment(Point p1, Point p2);
    //SET-METHODS
    void setEnd1(Point p1);
    void setEnd2(Point p2);

    //get-methods
    Point getEnd1();
    Point getEnd2();

    //calculations
    double slope();
    double length();
};
#endif
```

LineSegment.cpp

```
  #include "LineSegment.hpp"
    LineSegment::LineSegment(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        double x_1 = p1.getXCoord();
        double y_1 = p1.getYCoord();
        setEnd1(p1);

        double y_2 = p2.getYCoord();
        double x_2 = p2.getXCoord();
        setEnd1(p2);
    }

//set functions
void LineSegment::setEnd1(Point p1)
{
    Point endp1 =  p1;
}

void LineSegment::setEnd2(Point p2)
{
    Point endp2 =  p2;
}

//get-methods
Point LineSegment:: getEnd1()
{
    return endp1;
}

Point LineSegment:: getEnd2()
{
    return endp2;
}

//calculations

double LineSegment::slope()
{
    return (y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1);
}

double LineSegment::length()
{
    return endp1.distanceTo(endp2);
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Point.hpp"
#include "LineSegment.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Point p1(-1.5, 0.0);
    Point p2(1.5, 4.0);
    double dist = p1.distanceTo(p2);

    LineSegment ls1(p1, p2);

    double length = ls1.length();
    std::cout << length << std::endl;
    double slope = ls1.slope();
    std::cout << slope << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Remove all the vertical white-space, which is making your code unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setters set *local* variables instead of setting class members.

For some reason you are declaring local variables with the same names as class members in your setter methods. Local variables hide class members. All modifications you perform modify these local variables, leaving class members untouched.

For example, here

```
void LineSegment::setEnd1(Point p1)
{
    Point endp1 = p1;
}
```

why did you declare a local variable `Point endp1` when you intent was (I suppose) to set the class member?

Comment: I was required to have a get and set function for the end points. Even though i don't use them the teacher may when he includes his own main(). I didn't realize that including the data type in front of the variable was essentially declaring new ones! Such a brain fart, thank you!!